# Values are not assigned if object parameters are changed after private method call in grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-2.2, grails-2.1

I have a method which calls private method. This method returns model. Once it is returned, I change some object values and render it.
On jsp when I print value of 'message' then I do not get that value. Here is the code

```
def model = myMeth();
model.objkey.message = 'check message'
render(view: "index", model: model)
```

private method

```
private def myMeth() {
.....
    [objkey: objvalue]
}
```

& gsp

```
<div class="message">${objkey?.message}</div>
```

But if I add value to message in private method before return then it's value is printed on gsp.

This is the private method which prints value in gsp

```
private def myMeth() {
    .....
  objvalue.message = 'check message'
  [objkey: objvalue]
}
```

This used to work well in grails 1.3.7 but why does this happen in grails 2.2.4

Comment: where and how you call `loadTerm()`?

Comment: Sorry .. it's myMeth()

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected in 2.2.4 with the below setup hitting `index` action. Is this the way you have yours set up?

```
//controller
def index(){
    def model = myMethod()
    model.objectKey.message = 'check message'
    render view: "index", model: model
}

private def myMethod(){
    def objectVal = [:]

    [objectKey: objectVal]
}

//grails-app/views/<controllerName>/index.gsp
<div>${objectKey?.message}</div> //renders appropriate message
```